# BlackBerry Java SDK < 6.0.0 on Mac

Tags: macos, blackberry, sdk

I have a brand new installation of Eclipse with BlackBerry Plugin for mac.
The Java SDK 6.0.0 is already installed, the only thing now is that I want to compile for minor version, like 4.5.0

I have tried :
Help -> Install New Sotftware... -> http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java

But it gives me an error.

"No repository found at http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java"

anyone had the same issue ?
It seems that it worked for some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if what you're trying is possible, I also couldn't get it to work. According to the RIM site, they don't support building apps on OS X for non-6.0 right now, and based on the workaround below, I think it might not be as simple as installing the packages from the Eclipse installer.

However, I found a great post on building BlackBerry apps on OS X, and since then I've been working on my MBP, and can't say I would turn back. Here's a summary of how I got it set up:

1. Install Eclipse (I am using 3.5, but it may not matter) and VirtualBox.
2. Create a new VM and install Windows (tested with XP SP3). This
   would probably work using VMWare Fusion or Parallels too.
3. On the VM, install Java 6 and the version of the BlackBerry JDE
   that matches your target OS.
4. In OS X, download
   [bb-ant-tools.jar](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) and move it
   to ~/.ant/lib.
5. Get an OS X version of preverify, which is included in the [Sun
   J2ME SDK 3.0 for OS
   X](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/downloads/sdk30-jsp-139759.html).
   Install it and either copy
   /Applications/Java_ME_SDK_3.0.app/Contents/Resources/bin/preverify to
   somewhere in your PATH or just add that directory to your PATH.
6. If you don't have one already, create the file ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist.
7. Edit this file with /Developer/Applications/Utilities/Property\
   List\ Editor.app/.
8. Create a new variable called PATH and set it to the value of your
   shell PATH, making sure that the directory containing preverify is
   included. This allows Ant, via Eclipse, to see the preverify command
   when Eclipse is launched from Eclipse.app and not from the command
   line. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-113982)
   for more details.
9. In OS X, create a directory for the BlackBerry components
   (something like "bb-components").
10. From the BlackBerry JDE installation in the VM, copy both "lib" and
    "bin" directories to this directory.
11. In Eclipse, create a new Java project.
12. Choose "Use an execution environment JRE:" and select Java 1.3.
13. Right click the project in the "Package Explorer" and select "Build
    Path" and then "Configure Build Path."
14. Add bb-components/lib/net_rim_api.jar as an "External JAR."
15. Remove the "JRE System Library." This is so that only BlackBerry
    supported classes will be offered via autocompletion etc.
16. Copy the attached minimal
    [build.xml](https://gist.github.com/727661) into the project.
17. Edit the build.xml to suit your environment (specifically the
    jde.home property) and anything else you want to customise.
18. Right click and select "Run as" and then "Ant Build" (the first
    one). You can also build using Ant on the command line, of course.

These were adapted from https://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/11/04/our-blackberry-development-environment

Good luck!

Comment: If BlackBerry doesn't support < 6.0.0 I guess this answer pretty much my question. But Thank you for giving me the alternative, I will definitely try that !!

Comment: You're welcome! Hope it works out for you. I didn't mention it but you would have to use JavaLoader.exe through VirtualBox if that's how you deploy to a device for testing during development. I don't think that's a plain Java program. On the other hand, SignatureTool.jar works fine in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I develop all of my BB apps on Mac hardware but I'm running Windows through Parallels.  Not better than having native Mac tools, but it works!

Comment: Yeah I have tried that, but I use a laptop, it is kinda slow running Eclipse on Parallels.